# parallelizing for loop in class with joblib: pickable error

Tags: python, class, for-loop, parallel-processing, joblib

I am trying to parallize the for loop inside the active_again function but I get this error message:

BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.

When I use the for loop which is commented out underneath the parallel line it is working fine. But at some point the code will have to work with larger numbers of C_Cells and I would need it to run faster.

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from joblib import Parallel, delayed #parallelise loops
import multiprocessing as mp

num_cores = mp.cpu_count()

loc = np.array([(-1,-1,0), (0,1,0),
              (1,1,0), (-1,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,-1,0), (1,-1,0),(-1,1,0), 
              (-1,1,1), (0,1,1), (1,1,1), (-1,0,1), (0,0,1), (1,0,1), 
              (-1,-1,1), (0,-1,1), (1,-1,1), (-1,1,-1), (0,1,-1), (1,1,-1), 
              (-1,0,-1), (0,0,-1), (1,0,-1), (-1,-1,-1), (0,-1,-1), (1,-1,-1)])

class C_Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, position0):
        self.c_position0=position0
     
class C_Cells(object):
    def __init__(self, pts, c_ncell):
        self.c_cells = np.array([C_Cell(pts[i]) for i in\
                               range(c_ncell)]) #array of cell objects according to prior samplep
        self.c_position = np.array([c_cell.c_position0 for c_cell in self.c_cells])
        self.q_cells=np.empty((0,1))   
        self.q_position=np.empty((0,3),dtype=int)#np.array([(0,0,0)])
    def go_inactive(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.q_position=np.vstack((self.q_position, self.c_position[i])) 
            self.q_cells=np.append(self.q_cells, self.c_cells[i])
            self.c_position=np.delete(self.c_position, (i), axis=0) #mother cell leaves division pool
            self.c_cells=np.delete(self.c_cells, (i), axis=0)
            
    def active_again(self,e_position,s_position):
        num_cores = mp.cpu_count()
        qs=np.array(range(self.q_cells.shape[0]))
        
        def inner_active_again(s):
            p=self.q_position[qs[::-1][s]]+loc        
            c = cdist(p, self.c_position)==0
            p=p[~c.any(axis=1)]
            d= cdist(p, e_position)==0
            p=p[~d.any(axis=1)]
            f=cdist(p, s_position)==0
            p=p[~f.any(axis=1)]
            g=cdist(p, self.q_position)==0
            p=p[~g.any(axis=1)]
            if p.shape[0]>0:
                self.c_position=np.vstack((self.c_position, self.q_position[qs[::-1][s]]))  #cell goes into quiescence pool
                self.c_cells=np.append(self.c_cells, self.q_cells[qs[::-1][s]])
                self.q_position=np.delete(self.q_position, (qs[::-1][s]), axis=0)  #cell get removed out of division pool
                self.q_cells=np.delete(self.q_cells, (qs[::-1][s]), axis=0)
                
        Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(inner_active_again)(i) for i in range(self.q_cells.shape[0]))
        # for i in range(self.q_cells.shape[0]):
        #     inner_active_again(i) 
            
            
####################
a=loc+1
c=loc-1
b=np.vstack((a,loc,c))
e_position=np.array([[1,2,3]])
s_position=np.array([[3,3,3]])

s_cells=1
c_ncell=52
l=C_Cells(b, c_ncell)

t=0
while t<100:
    t+=1
    print('t=',t)
    l.go_inactive()
    l.active_again(e_position,s_position)
```

Any help regarding this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this can actually be parallelized? The called function mutate the shared attribute of `self`. Even assuming such a thing would not cause any race conditions, the `np.delete` are likely causing a quadratic time execution... I think using a more efficient algorithm is certainly better than trying to run an inefficient algorithm on more computing resources.

Comment: sorry, i am just a python beginner. would you have any suggestions to make this code more efficient and faster? it is only a small part of a bigger code but the active_again function takes most of the running time